# .Net Core application randomly stops responding. There is a sudden increase in pid count and it gets stopped

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

My .Net Core application is hosted on AWS, randomly it stops responding. There is a sudden increase in pid count and it gets stopped. This application is using saas model and there are too many httpclient calls to other apps as well. After so many effort I am unable to find the root cause behind this

```
    //call begins here
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);

        if (Entity.isJsonAcceptHeader) client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        else client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html");
        if (Entity.Context != null)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("WebsiteGuid", GlobalFunctions.GetWebsiteGuidFromHeader(Entity.Context.Request));
        else
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("WebsiteGuid", WebSiteGuid);
        if (Entity.Context != null)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("LanguageGuid", GlobalFunctions.GetLanguageGuidFromHeader(Entity.Context.Request));
        else
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("LanguageGuid", LanguageGuid);

        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(Entity.url);
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            response = await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: How can we possibly help diagnose your issue when we can't see your code. You only mention `HttpClient` calls, are you [using that correctly](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)?

Comment: I am making that call with using only, but not sure if I should use HttpClient object as static

Comment: You shouldn't do it like that, always use a static `HttpClient`.